# Getting Substring with NSRange

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, substring, nsrange

I try to read out the url's of youtubevideos from this link: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?author=channelname

I tried it like this:

```
NSRange startRange = [ret rangeOfString:@"<media:content url='http"];
NSRange endRange = [ret rangeOfString:@"'"];

NSRange searchRange = NSMakeRange(startRange.location , endRange.location);
NSLog(@"Link: %@",[ret substringWithRange:searchRange]);
```

The output is just: `<media:content`

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Can you put up original string ? I mean value of ret

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where is my mistake?

The mistake is that you're not using [the right tool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the task.

Anyways, you seem to be confusing the length and the ending location of ranges. `NSMakeRange()` takes a location and a length, not the starting and the ending location.

Also, don't expect `- [NSString rangeOfString:]` to magically guess what you are trying to do. It will return the first occurrence of the given substring, and here that is not what you want.

Comment: And what do I need instead of NSRange?

Comment: @Phil Did you check the link in the answer?